# Always keep a local copy of some folders in the iCloud synced files

Tags: icloud, backup, data-synchronization

I keep almost everything synced with my iCloud drive. It removes from local storage the things I rarely use and I love the feature, however, there are a few folders which I would like to keep synced and always local, even if I don't touch them for a long time. How to add such an exception?

Comment: I also have this question / need!

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but in Ventura (might work on older versions too) you can select all files in the folder, and from the action toolbar item in the Finder window, select 'Download'. As I say, not ideal, but it will at least make all the *current* items in the folder available offline. Still hoping for a better answer/solution in the future.